# jquery .each works only on the first element

Tags: jquery, html, loops, indexing, each

I'm having trouble understanding jqueries .each.
I have the following code:

```
$('#testDiv').each(function(index, domEle){    
    $(this).text(index);
});
```

and the following HTML

```
<div id="p18">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div id="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="p19">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div id="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="p20">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div id="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the script runs it only works for the first testDiv, as it correctly sets the text to 0, however the other testDivs.

My overall goal is to write a script that will set the height of the div based on another div's height. The heights differ so I think a loop structure is the way to go (unless I am mistaken?)

What am I doing incorrectly with the jq code?

Comment: An ID should be unique in the entire page, the behavior you observe is totally normal.

Comment: your HTML aint valid :) duplicate id <no no>

Comment: fix the issue with multiple elements having the same ID, and then try using  `$.each` on a class, e.g. `$('.inner').each(function...`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use the same `#id` for different elements. Try to rename the rest and you'll get the result you want

Or do this (works without adding any classes - cleaner code)

```
$('.inner div').each(function(index, domEle){    
    $(this).text(index);
});
```

Comment: I have no id's set for any of my selected elements. In my case, adding domEle to my function did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`id` selector returns maximum one element.

**You should never have more than one element with the same id.** it's an invalid HTML

This will work, but you should fix the HTML instead:

```
$('div[id="testDiv"]')...
```

What you should really do is:

```
<div id="p18">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div class="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="p19">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div class="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then select by the class:

```
$('.testDiv')...
```

Comment: *facepalm* cant believe I forgot about that xD Thanks :)

Comment: @Skye. Just please don't use my attribute selector workaround. it's still an invalid HTML.

Comment: No worries. The testDivs are being added with jq so its a a quick fix

Answer (score 3):

That's not a problem with the `each` method. You have specified the same `id` for several elements, which is not supported.

Use a class instead, and you can find all the elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xaL4n/

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid html. Ids need to be unique. You should change `id="testDiv"` to `class="testDiv"`

**HTML**:

```
<div id="p20">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>...</span>
        <p class="right">...</p>
        <div class="testDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('.testDiv').each(function(index, domEle){    
    $(this).text(index);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not specify same div id in a html page.

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

insteed of that, try

```
<div class="testDiv"></div>
```

and your function should look like

```
$('.testDiv').each(function(index, domEle){    
$(this).text(index);
```

});